# Expensive gremlin query - can it be made more efficient?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I have this gremlin query which I'm issuing against CosmosDB database using the Gremlin.net driver:

```
g
  .V('Alice')
  .as('v')
  .V('Bob')
  .coalesce(
     __.inE('spokeWith')
    .where(
       outV()
      .as('v')),
    addE('spokeWith')
    .property('date', '10.02.2019 20:16:38').from('v'))
```

The idea is to add an edge between two nodes if it does not exists.

The problem is: This query seems to be very expensive, as Azure charges me around 600-1600 Request Units for it. This way, I'm hitting my throughput limit very quickly.

Is there a better way to express this query so that it's cheaper in terms of Request Units?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how CosmosDB comes up with the request units, but I don't think there's any more efficient way to create an edge if it doesn't exist. In both scenarios, whether the edge already exists or not, the traversal really just uses the minimum amount of resources:

```
gremlin> g.addV().property(id, 'Alice').addV().property(id, 'Bob').iterate()
gremlin> g.V('Alice').as('v'). /* CREATE */
           V('Bob').
           coalesce(inE('spokeWith').where(outV().as('v')),
                    addE('spokeWith').property('date', 'xyz').from('v')).
           profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[Alice])@[v]                                    1           1           0.056    13.06
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[Bob])                                          1           1           0.054    12.74
CoalesceStep([[VertexStep(IN,[spokeWith],edge),...                     1           1           0.319    74.20
  VertexStep(IN,[spokeWith],edge)                                                              0.041
  WhereTraversalStep([WhereStartStep, ProfileSt...                                             0.009
  AddEdgeStep({date=[xyz], ~from=[[SelectOneSte...                     1           1           0.105
    SelectOneStep(last,v)                                              1           1           0.016
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           0.430        -
gremlin> g.V('Alice').as('v'). /* GET */
           V('Bob').
           coalesce(inE('spokeWith').where(outV().as('v')),
                    addE('spokeWith').property('date', 'xyz').from('v')).
           profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[Alice])@[v]                                    1           1           0.056     9.68
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[Bob])                                          1           1           0.018     3.09
CoalesceStep([[VertexStep(IN,[spokeWith],edge),...                     1           1           0.509    87.23
  VertexStep(IN,[spokeWith],edge)                                      1           1           0.044
  WhereTraversalStep([WhereStartStep, ProfileSt...                     1           1           0.414
    WhereStartStep                                                     1           1           0.036
    EdgeVertexStep(OUT)                                                1           1           0.331
    WhereEndStep(v)                                                                            0.012
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           0.583        -
```

As you can see, there's only 1 traverser in any case; it can't be cheaper than that. Well, unless there are other incoming `spokeWith` edges to Bob and CosmosDB is not able to optimize the adjacent vertex filter (`where(outV().as('v'))`) - in that case, you would end up having more traversers. However, I don't know how CosmosDB handles this case under the hood. Perhaps try to `.profile()` your query directly against CosmosDB and pay attention to the number of traversers.
But from a TinkerPop perspective, your traversal is as optimal as it can be.